# Dictionary text file Python

Tags: python-3.x

text

```
Donald Trump:
791697302519947264,1477604720,Ohio USA,Twitter for iPhone,5251,1895
Join me live in Springfield, Ohio!
Lit
<<<EOT
781619038699094016,1475201875,United States,Twitter for iPhone,31968,17246
While Hillary profits off the rigged system, I am fighting for you! Remember the simple phrase: #FollowTheMoney... 
<<<EOT

def read(text):
    with open(text,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
```

Is there a way that i can separate each information for the candidates So for example for Donald Trump it should be

```
[
[Donald Trump],
[791697302519947264[[791697302519947264,1477604720,'Ohio USA','Twitter for iPhone',5251,18951895], 'Join['Join me live in Springfield, Ohio! Lit']Lit']],
[781619038699094016[[781619038699094016,1475201875,'United States','Twitter for iPhone',31968,1724617246], 'While['While Hillary profits off the rigged system, I am fighting for you! Remember the simple phrase: #FollowTheMoney...']']]
]
```

The format of the file is the following:

ID,DATE,LOCATION,SOURCE,FAVORITE_COUNT,RETWEET_COUNT text(the tweet)

So basically after the 6 headings, everything after that is a tweet till '<<

Also is there a way i can do this for every candidate in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need a multi-dimensional list (I would pick tuples and dictionaries if possible) but this seems to produce the output you asked for:

```
>>> txt = """Donald Trump:
... 791697302519947264,1477604720,Ohio USA,Twitter for iPhone,5251,1895
... Join me live in Springfield, Ohio!
... Lit
... <<<EOT
... 781619038699094016,1475201875,United States,Twitter for iPhone,31968,17246
... While Hillary profits off the rigged system, I am fighting for you! Remember the simple phrase: #FollowTheMoney... 
... <<<EOT
... Another Candidate Name:
... 12312321,123123213,New York USA, Twitter for iPhone,123,123
... This is the tweet text!
... <<<EOT"""
>>> 
>>> 
>>> buffer = []
>>> tweets = []
>>> 
>>> for line in txt.split("\n"):
...     if not line.startswith("<<<EOT"):
...         buffer.append(line)
...     else:
...         if buffer[0].strip().endswith(":"):
...             tweets.append([buffer.pop(0).rstrip().replace(":", "")])
...         metadata = buffer.pop(0).split(",")
...         tweet = [" ".join(line for line in buffer).replace("\n", " ")]
...         tweets.append([metadata, tweet])
...         buffer = []    
... 
>>> 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> 
>>> pprint(tweets)
[['Donald Trump'],
 [['791697302519947264',
   '1477604720',
   'Ohio USA',
   'Twitter for iPhone',
   '5251',
   '1895'],
  ['Join me live in Springfield, Ohio! Lit']],
 [['781619038699094016',
   '1475201875',
   'United States',
   'Twitter for iPhone',
   '31968',
   '17246'],
  ['While Hillary profits off the rigged system, I am fighting for you! Remember the simple phrase: #FollowTheMoney... ']],
 ['Another Candidate Name'],
 [['12312321',
   '123123213',
   'New York USA',
   ' Twitter for iPhone',
   '123',
   '123'],
  ['This is the tweet text!']]]
>>>
```

Comment: jDo im doing dictionary with tuple but the thing is i can only output the first tweet

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite understanding... but here is my example to read a file line by line then add that line to a string of text to post to twitter.

```
candidates = open("FILEPATH WITH DOUBLE \") #example "C:\\users\\fox\\desktop\\candidates.txt"

for candidate in candidates():
  candidate = candidate.rstrip('\n') #removes new line(this is mandatory)
  #next line post means post to twitter
  post("propaganda here " + candidate + "more propaganda)
```

note for every line in that file this code will post to twitter
ex.. 20 lines means twenty twitter posts

Comment: if you want to post all that info for just trump then put it on one line in the file